# Calling module inside for loop

Tags: verilog

I want to call a module inside for loop bellow is the sample code but it show following error . Please note we use synopsis cad tools to compile

Error:

> Error-[SE] Syntax error   Following verilog source has syntax error : 
>   "andgate.v", 14: token is 'and'
>         and a (outputs[0],input1[0],input2);

The code is:

```
module ands (
    input1,
    input2,
    outputs
);
    input [2:0] input1;
    input input2;
    output [2:0] outputs;

always@(input1 or input2)
begin
   integer itr;

    and a (outputs[0],input1[0],input2);

    genvar itr;
    generate
        for (itr = 1 ; itr <= 2; itr = itr+1)
begin : gen_loop
            and a(outputs[itr],input1[itr],outputs[itr-1]);
end
    endgenerate
end

endmodule
```

Comment: Hi, I don't think that instantiating module inside an `always@` block is allowed. Put your instances outside the always block.

Comment: Read up on how always / sensitive lists work. Where and when they are needed.

Answer (score 1):

`generate` statement cannot be used within an `always` block.
module cannot be instantiated within an `always` block.
`itr` must be a `genvar`

So, something like that should work in your case:

```
module ands (
  input1,
  input2,
  outputs
);
  input [2:0] input1;
  input input2;
  output [2:0] outputs;

  and a (outputs[0],input1[0],input2);

  genvar itr;
  generate
    for (itr = 1 ; itr <= 2; itr = itr+1)
    begin : gen_loop
        and a(outputs[itr],input1[itr],outputs[itr-1]);
    end
  endgenerate
endmodule
```

Comment: Or create an array of instances `and a[2:0] ( outputs[2:0], input1[2:0], {outputs[1:0],input2} );` (supported since Verilog-95). Or behavioral `assign outputs[2:0] = input1[2:0] & {outputs[1:0],input2};`

Comment: I tried with Serge provided code but still it show following error : Following verilog source has syntax error :
   Illegal port or variable declaration
  "andgate.v", 12: token is ';'
    genvar itr;
               ^

Comment: @RiazUlHaqueMian this looks strange. Sounds like you missed some closing parenthesis. which tool did you use to compile? it compiles for me.